# What is Checksum mismatch warning?

Tags: android, warnings, logcat, checksum

In my app suddenly occurs Checksum mismatch Warning.

Yesterday I add a ViewPager and add parallax effect and auto scrolling function.

and now it working fine. but I found some warning in my logcat.

[image]

is this negligible? or ignorable issue?